# How to display a notification in adobe air for android

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I want to display notifications in my Adobe Air App for Android using Adobe Flash and Action Script 3.0 .

I want to use notifications for reminding people to update my app when a new version gets released, so how do I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: To access things like notifications and a device's volume buttons, you need to use ANEs. If you look up something like "Android notification ANE," you'll find what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

As DefinitelyNotAPlesiosaur has mentioned, using an ANE is the way to go.

You can find some free ANE's to use here:

http://www.riaxe.com/blog/200-adobe-air-anes/

but I would highly recommend district as they publish multiple well documented ANE's with example files and offer excellent support.

http://airnativeextensions.com

It sounds like you would need either Notifications or Push Notifications if your message was to appear when the user is not using the app, or Dialog if the message appears whilst the user is using the app.

Comment: Is there any tutorial on the basics of ANEs?  What are ANEs? How to add and use them?